# Eclipse error using Maven filtering in persistence.xml

Tags: maven, jar, persistence, filtering

I have a Maven project with JPA using hibernate.

I had to specify a jar file to load external classes in `persistence.xml` located in `src/main/resources/META-INF`

```
<persistence unit name="PersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA"
    ...
    <jar-file>lib/${project.persistencejar}.jar</jar-file>
```

using Maven filtering (the filename can change based on various Maven settings).
I instruct then Maven to filter by including in the `pom.xml`

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>META-INF/persistence.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

and running `mvn clean install` produces a deployable and working ear.

The problem is: if I keep JPA Facet enabled in Eclipse project configuration, Eclipse complains that

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - JAR file "lib/${project.persistencejar}.jar" cannot be resolved
    - The path to the JAR file will vary on your runtime environment. Please make sure the 
      specified path fits your particular environment.
```

and disabling it doesn't build my JPA project everytime that I update it (thus having to run Maven everytime there is a change in the persistence. Is there a workaround to tell Eclipse where he can find the jar at development time? Or maybe I am using the wrong approach to filtering?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it this way:

in `persistence.xml` substitute the whole `<jar-file>` tag, i.e.

```
<persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    ...
    <!-- here is where the jar file is supposed to go -->
    ${importjarfile}
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```

Then include in `pom.xml` the property

```
<properties>        
    <!-- jar of persistence -->
    <importjarfile><![CDATA[<jar-file>lib/${project.persistencejar}.jar</jar-file>]]></importjarfile>
</properties>
```

or alternatively in `src/main/filters/profilename.properties` file the line

```
importjarfile = <jar-file>lib/${project.persistencejar}.jar</jar-file>
```

In this way Eclipse won't see the `jar-file` tag and won't complain. At build time, maven will generate the correct persistence xml.

Comment: If I add ${importjarfile} Eclipse Luna will give the following error

cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'persistence-unit' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

Any suggestion?

Comment: you might have to disable the schema validation. I did so by removing the attributes `xmlns:xsi` and `xsi:schemaLocation` from the `<persistence>` root tag

Answer (score 6):

If the problem only in incorrect error message from Eclipse, you can disable it in

> Window->Preferences->Java
>   Persistence->JPA->Errors/Warnings->Persistence unit

Just set **"Ignore"** for **"JAR file cannot be resolved"**